# My checkbox doesn't pass it's value field when serialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, serialization, checkbox

I have a form that I have a checkbox.
I am using jQuery `serialize` to post the values through an ajax call.

When my checkbox is checked, it is not passing the actual value of the field.

My HTML is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="dispatch_emails_active" name="dispatch_emails_active" value="Yes" />
```

However when I POST the form through serialize:

```
alert($("#edit-form").serialize());
```

My value comes through as:

```
id=3&code=DEM&name=Demo+Company&dispatch_emails_active=
```

As you can see above, it doesn't pass the value through, just an empty field.
If I uncheck the field, the field doesn't get passed at all (which is what I expected).

Any ideas?

Comment: Working for me http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/ov0Lnz8a/

Comment: @Moogs- I know, I saw an example on a JsFiddle and it was working, so no idea what is going on with my form!